# Circuit Requirements for a 30 min continuous on off cycle

Tags: timer, 12v, delay, duty-cycle

I would like to build a circuit (preferably using components from old common electronics like a VCR or whatever) that continuously cycles on/off in ~ 30 min intervals. Input voltage is from a 12v groundless DC inverter that's plugged into the wall. The 30 min on/off cycle is to power a 12V 0.23amp computer fan. A period of 60 min with a 50% duty cycle would seemingly work fine here.

The optimal answer would include additional information on how I could modify the circuit (if needed) to increase the time delay. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to modify the period, the duty cycle or both?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that is definitely much more appropriate terminology here. Honestly whichever is simpler I'm thinking having a set period of an hour with a duty cycle of 25%-75% would be more than sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Just a 50% duty cycle would be fine if it makes the build of this more simple and doable.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is one of those cheap, mechanical, store-bought timers.

Comment: Sound like a job for ready built timer or clock. Even mechanical one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple circuit for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV1vkk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And program the ATtiny85 to flip the PIO port on and off once per 30 minutes. Arduino software is more than good enough for this.

My personal favorite microcontroller for this kind of task is AVR, but any  microcontroller can do this.

Even being a 8-pin device, ATtiny85 (or the PIC the other answer suggested) still have enough IO lines to allow an external device talk to it, changing both the frequency and duty ratio.

If you don't want to use a phone charger powering this a fully charged 18650 Li-Po can keep it running for months if not years.

Comment: You missed the obligatory diode across the relay coil, yes?

Comment: @EMFieldsMI have dutifully noted that this is not an actual relay, but an SSR.

Comment: AArghhh!!! Right you are.

Comment: But you drew it as a mechanical relay.  If you mean SSR, show a SSR.  Your circuit as it stands now is wrong, no matter what else the text around it says.

Comment: @OlinLathrop There is no SSR in CircuitLab and I have to use something to represent it.

Comment: No, you don't just "use something" if the symbol you want isn't there.  Doing so makes your circuit wrong.  There are always options.  If CircuitLab doesn't have the symbol, make one, or don't use CircuitLab.  A wrong schematic is a wrong schematic.  It's not the reader's issue that you were unwilling to draw a correct one.  Fix it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am conveying an idea here so stop being caustic. As long as the idea is correctly expressed I don't think one wrong representation or two will be a problem. Also given his 30 minutes interval, there is nothing preventing him from actually use a mechanical relay, just add your diode.

Answer (score 4):

30 minutes is a long time for analog electronics to time.  This would be done by a small current on a capacitor eventually changing its voltage past a threshold.  Unfortunately, for such a long time the current to charge and discharge the capacitor will be too large relative to the leakage current of the capacitor and surrounding circuitry.

A simple way to do this is to use a microcontroller.  Even the cheap and tiny PIC 10F200 can do this easily.  The internal oscillator of the micro is good to a few percent.  It runs at 1 MHz instruction rate, which you can easily divide down by whatever number you want to get arbitrarily large time delays, all at the same accuracy as the main clock.

Other options are to count power line cycles (since that is often a handy existing signal with well known frequency).  However, all these schemes will take more hardware than a PIC 10F200, which only needs power, ground, and a bypass cap to change the state of a pin every 30 minutes.  Of course that can also be easily modified for different delays or patterns.

Comment: Sir, if you want, adjust answer to show how to wire up and prog the PIC 10F200 and this would answer my question fully.

Comment: @rhill45, this is a "teach you how to do it yourself" site, not a "give away professional services for free" site.

Comment: @rhill: Wiring up the micro is trivial. You connect power and ground, and make sure there is a 1 uF or so bypass cap across the power/ground pins. The tricky part, if you're not used to such things, is programming the micro. If you plan to do electronics projects in general, this is a really useful skill to have. Once you have been thru the process a few times, writing the code for a simple project like this is easy.  This would be a great learning project.

Comment: Olin good point on the learning investment here. And yes, it's a tall order to request that info when these chips have an instruction manual. Thanks for all the excellent info today. @ThePhoton isn't this a question and answer forum? There is a designated DIY SE http://diy.stackexchange.com/ ;-)